# Backuppc is too slow

Tags: backuppc

We have a Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS installed on a Dell powerEdge.
It has 4x2 TB HDD in RAID-5 configuration.

The thing is, we have to periodically backup 4TB of data and it takes 7 days for a full backup and 3 days for incremental.

Is there a way to improve this speed?

Comment: At what speed is it transfering this data? Perhaps you need faster disk drives?

Comment: 8Mb/sec (very slow indeed)

Comment: how are you tranferring this data - is it USB, Ethernet or another?

Comment: Would it be an idea to look at a different backup strategy instead of merely looking at the speed?  I mean, how fast must a medium be to shave of 2-6 days of the time to finish a backup. I think you need to approach a specialized vendor to see what new techniques are available.

Comment: Tim > Those disks are connected to a RAID-5 controller.

Comment: so what kind of tool would be better than backuppc?

Comment: are you still looking for answers here?